# Disable or enable an html5 image with javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to disable all images of my game by using enable or disable function, but it does not works!
can you help me with this? I have no idea how to disable or enable onclick function on a single image

Tryed this:

```
<div><img id="red" src = "rojo.png" onclick="setColorRojo()"/></div>

function enable(){
        document.getElementById("red").disabled = false; 


    }

    function disable(){
        document.getElementById("red").disabled = true;

    }
```

Comment: you can't disable images. disabling is for form fields...

Comment: there is no disabling an image. perhaps you should set a boolean flag as a variable that `setColorRojo` would do

Comment: You mean you want to hide them?  Replace them with red squares?

Comment: @DanielA.White I got it, So I can build that with a loop right?

Comment: @dtanders no, just disable it, like when a disabled button appear (unable to click)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Images can't be disabled and enabled in the way you're trying to. Try using a flag to determine the state of the application instead:

```
var enabled = true;

function enable(){
    enabled = true;
}

function disable(){
    enabled = false;
}

function setColorRojo() {
    if (enabled) {
        //Set color or do any other actions here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't actually disable an `<img>`, that's more for `<input>` tags. You can add/remove an attribute on the img and if present, stop execution in `setColorRojo()`:

```
function enable(){
    document.getElementById("red").setAttribute('disabled', 'true');
}
function disable(){
    document.getElementById("red").setAttribute('disabled', 'false');
}

<img id="red" src="rojo.png" onclick="setColorRojo(this);"/>

function setColorRojo(img){
     if(img.getAttribute('disabled') === 'true') return;
     //do the rest of the function
}
```

Comment: You coulr also just remove/re-add the `onclick` attribute in these enable/disable functions, or remove/re-add the `click` binding programmatically

Answer (score 1):

A simple trick is to use pointerEvents css property.
By setting it to none, mouse click events on the image are disabled, while setting it to auto enables mouse click events.

```
function disableClick(imageID) {
    document.getElementById(imageID).style.pointerEvents = "none";
}

function enableClick(imageID) {
    document.getElementById(imageID).style.pointerEvents = "auto";
}
```

Works in Chrome and Firefox.